# UNIX Script not reading the folders with spaces

Tags: scripting

I have a UNIX script which is supposed to scan all the folders and return the files older than speciific amount of time. I gave the logic as below, but the script is not able to read the folders with spaces. Can anyone please help on how to make this work?

dir='/a/b/test';

script is scanning all the sub directories after test, but not able to scan the directories with spaces, example 'test script'.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the script you are using so that we can help you with that rather than shooting blindly..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 2):

So you have something like this:

```
$ foo='my dir'
$ ls $foo
my: no file or directory found
dir: no file or directory found
```

Instead, try this:

```
$ foo='my dir'
$ ls "$foo"
```

Or even better:

```
$ ls "${foo}"
```

Both of these methods shield the [:space:] character from being interpreted by the shell, and ensures that it is read as a [:space:] character, not the breaking point for a command.

It's a very good habit to get into when writing shell scripts!